# Pass an object to body with Guzzle

Tags: php, rest, guzzle

I am performing some calls to a REST API, using Guzzle, which I found very handy.

I want to pass an object, which is normally sent with -d flag via cURL, but without the expected results at the moment.

```
$request = $client->post('rest/user/current/resources/test', [], [
                                     'auth' => [self::USERNAME, self::PASSWORD],
                                     'body' =>  ['skeletonTest' => $skeletonTest ]
                                    ]);

            $response =$request->send();

           $this->dd($response);
```

From the docs:

```
-d 'skeletonTest={skeletonTest}'
```

First issue:

```
 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

while the credentials are correct.

Second issue:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: response in ....
```

What could be the problem here?
I have tried also using:

```
$request= $client->createRequest('POST','....');
```

but     getBody() does not return something meaningful.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**

When I am providing this:

```
            $request = $client->post('rest/user/current/resources/test', [
                                     'auth' => [self::USERNAME, self::PASSWORD],
                                     'body' =>  ['skeletonTest' => $skeletonTest ]
                                    ]);

           $this->dd($request->send()->getBody());
```

the output is :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid resource type: object' in
```

So, no 401 but Invalid Argument when I remove the second argument in the post() method.
$skeletonTest is an object of an empty class (stdClass).

Comment: do your auth values need to be in the header or body of the request. If they need to be in the header, you need to move the `'auth' => []` into the `[]` just after the URL. However this depends on the API and where it is expecting the credentials to come from.

Comment: Copied from another function:

        $response = $client->get('rest/admin/current/resources/user/verify_password', [
                               'auth' =>  [ self::USERNAME, self::PASSWORD]
                              ]); 

The above part works expectedly.

Docs suggest that auth credentials should be passed via the -u flag using cURL, whereas the data via the -d flag.
Could the passed object's format be the only issue, given the thrown exception?